# How to count OR conditions which are "true" in a If loop and execute different code for different count results

Tags: if-statement, casting, type-conversion, boolean-logic, logical-operators

I have 5 different OR conditions in a If loop:

```
if(cond1 || cond2 || .... || cond5)
```

All conditions are bool type in C#

The problem is I have to execute certain code if any one condition is true, another code when any two conditions are true, another code when any three are true, another code when any four are true, another code when all are true and another code when none is true.

How do I solve the problem?

My approach is:

```
if(1 == (Convert.ToInt(cond1) + Convert.ToInt(cond2) + ... + Convert.ToInt(cond5)))
{
  //Code1
}
else if(2 == (Convert.ToInt(cond1) + Convert.ToInt(cond2) + ... + Convert.ToInt(cond5)))
{
  //Code2
}
.... and so on...
```

Is there any better approach?

Comment: Why not add them all and _then_ do the conditions?

Comment: @MooingDuck I can only add as integer. Adding bool variables gives error: "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool'"

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/987bf7863f2f01ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count =     
Convert.ToInt32(cond1)+Convert.ToInt32(cond1)+...+Convert.ToInt32(cond1);

switch(count)
{
    case 1:
    //your code here
    break;
    .
    .
    .
    case 5:
    //your code here
    break;
}
```

This might help you..